# ip address in java valid or not

Tags: java, regex, validation, ip-address, port-number

I want to validate IP address with or without a port number using regex. My input string would be `IP:PORT` or just `IP`. I want only one `regex` which will be validating `IP:PORT` or `IP` both.

My IP address regex is:

```
^(?:(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

Can someone let me know how to add optional port numbers to this existing regex?

Comment: assuming your IP regex is good: `^(?:(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:[:]\d{2,5})?$`

Comment: Two things: use the (`) symbol when you have code, not to wrap words. Second, the best solution in this case would be to not use a regex at all.

Comment: ... or to use regex to parse, and another mechanism to validate the IP component values. Google search for good regex for IP's:  http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated: Google for it: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

You are also trying to do too much in one place. Use the regex for what it's good for, and then use other smarts for the places where regex is not the right tool. In your case, don't try to validate the value ranges for the IP address in the regex, but in the post-process:

```
.... ^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})(:(\d{1,5}))?$

byte[] ip = new byte[4];
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    int bt = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(i));
    if (bt < 0 || bt > 255) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Byte value " + bt + " is not valid.");
    }
    ip[i-1] = (byte)bt;
}
integer port = 0;
if (matcher.group(6) != null) {
  port = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(6));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
^(?:(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:1\d?\d|[1-9]?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-‌​5])(?:[:]\d+)?$
```

Comment: Edited now. You can use regextester.com

Answer (score 1):

class Solution{

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(in.hasNext()){

        String IP = in.next();

        System.out.println(IP.matches(new MyRegex().pattern));

    }



}
```

}

class MyRegex  {

```
                                           String pattern="^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                                                                          "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                                                                          "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                                                                          "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

            }
```

private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN =

```
                           "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                           "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                           "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

                           "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
```

ı used this solution from this website:

https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0):

Use trailing `?` to mark optional part, i.e. add `(:\\d+)` to the end of your regex.

Comment: Can u please Add port validation in my regex. that the main thing i dnt understand how to add optional things in existing?